# Edited - Python plot persistence windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Each time I launch my program, my plots are erased after each execution.

I would like the following situation:

1. Launch program 1 and plot in figure 1
2. Stop the execution of program 1
3. Lauch program 2 and plot in figure 1
4. Retrieve a pdf file where the plot of program 1 and program 2 are superimposed

here is my code:

```python
z = np.zeros(5) 
fig,axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
fig.subplots_adjust()

lig,col = 0,0
axarr[lig,col].plot(tt,z[0,:],'k')

#plt.ion() 
#plt.draw()                                                                         
plt.show(block=True)
#plt.show()
```

**EDIT:** Ok maybe I could solve this problem with the following approach:
Is it possible to get the ax of a figure that was opened by an other excetion of of program ?

Comment: Maybe it is handy for other programmers to see the code you already have, that is one of the rules here, on StackOverflow. [See this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some more explanation is highly appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.show(block=True)` should work.

Other hack would be using pause function as shown below:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
pylab.plot(range(10), range(10))
pylab.pause(2**31-1)
```

Comment: block=True, I put this but I don't want to block the figure, I want to terminate and then launch program 2.

For your solution, I sould lauch the program 2 in parallel ?

Comment: the script keeps the window open after it is run. then you can launch program2

Comment: Please mark it checked and upvote, if it was helpful. :)